# Fast forward or rewind with AVAssetReaderTrackOutput

Tags: ios, video

I'm implementing a video player, which process video frame with `OpenGL` then show processed video frame in `GLKView`.

I use `[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer]` to decode video frame, but no API for fast forward or rewind is found. Some other apps have implemented the feature I described.

Is there any API for `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` to fast forward or rewind , or should I switch to another solution to decode video frame?

Answer (score 0):

AVAssetReaderTrackOutput is subclass of AVAssetReaderOutput, fast forward and rewind could be implemented with [AVAssetReaderOutput resetForReadingTimeRanges]